# 90 degree counter-clockwise rotation around a point

Tags: linear-algebra

How do you do a 90 degree counter-clockwise rotation around a point? I know around the origin it's $(-y,x)$, but what would it be around a point?

$$(-y - a,x - b)$$
Where $(a,b)$ is the rotation point.

Comment: @S.C.B. whoever edited it, is that the right answer?

Comment: No, I just reformatted yours.

Comment: got it. thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Subtract the point, rotate around origin, add the point back:

$$(-(y-b)+a, (x-a) + b)$$

Answer (score 3):

Given any point $p=\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
x \\
y \end{array} \right]$ and a center of rotation $c=\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
a \\
b \end{array} \right]$ we can construct the vector $\vec{d}=p-c$ which is the vector that goes from $p$ to $c$.

Then we can create a rotation matrix $T=\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
\cos{\theta} & -\sin{\theta} \\
\sin{\theta} & \cos{\theta} \end{array} \right] $ where $\theta$ is the counter-clockwise rotation angle.

Then the rotated point $p'$ is given by

$$p'=T\vec{d}+c$$

For your example, $\vec{d}=\left[\begin{matrix}
x-a\\
y-b
\end{matrix}\right]$, $T=\left[\begin{matrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{matrix}\right]$ and $c=\left[\begin{matrix}
a\\
b
\end{matrix}\right]$, so

$$p'= \left[\begin{matrix}
b-y\\
x-a
\end{matrix}\right]+\left[\begin{matrix}
a\\
b
\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}
a+b-y\\
x+b-a
\end{matrix}\right]$$